# how to restrict Qlineedit input?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I have a QLineEdit and I want to restrict inputting some characters and in it.
I have used QValidator but I found out that it could not (or maybe I don't know how to) restrict inputting some characters only as what it did was allowing certain inputs only, further more, setting input restriction like [a-z-A-Z-0-9] or such will also limiting Unicode characters input, which is not what I want. Is there a way that can setup a block list to prevent inputting some illegal characters? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to implement your own `QValidator` as I show below:

```
class LettersValidator(QValidator):
    def __init__(self, options, *args, **kwargs):
        QValidator.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._options = options

    def validate(self, value, pos):
        if len(value) > 0:
            if value[-1] in self._options:
                return QValidator.Acceptable, value, pos
        else:
            if value == "":
                return QValidator.Intermediate, value, pos
        return QValidator.Invalid, value, pos


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QLineEdit()
    w.setValidator(LettersValidator("tam"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```